# Unable to iterate over List<MultipartFile>

Tags: java, iterator, multipartform-data

following is my function for uploading multiple files from a WebPage. My files are in List of MultipartFile --> files variable.I'm unable to iterate over every file. However log.info("file"+files) printed file[]. Which means files returns '[]'. What does this mean? Where am I going wrong?

```
public String addNodeAndDocNew(TreeType treeType, ObjectId parentNodeId, NodeType nodeType, String displayName, String attrList, List<MultipartFile> files, String userId,
        String passwd) {
    String result = "";
    log.info("file"+ files);
    log.info("userId=" + userId);
    log.info("passwd=" + passwd);
    log.info("nodeType=" + nodeType);
    log.info("displayName=" + displayName);
    if (attrList != null)
        log.info("attributesList=" + attrList.toString());
    ObjectId nodeId = null;
    for(MultipartFile file : files)
    {
        log.info("Yess");
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Nothing attached, just adding node, not the doc");
            nodeId = addNode(treeType, parentNodeId, nodeType, displayName, attrList, userId, passwd);
            if (nodeId != null)
                log.info("Just added node, no doc sent");
        }

        else {
            log.info("file=" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            nodeId = addNode(treeType, parentNodeId, nodeType, displayName, attrList, userId, passwd);
            if (nodeId != null) {
                docService.uploadDoc(nodeId, file, userId, passwd);
                log.info("Added node, and doc");
            } else {
                log.info("addNode() returned null");
            }
        }

    if (nodeId != null) {
        log.info("addNodeAndDoc completed for node id : " + nodeId.toString());
        result += nodeId.toString()+ "@@";
    } else
        return null;
    }
    log.info("Yess1");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In which line is the problem (there: "for(MultipartFile file : files)")? What is your output, if you run this program?

Answer (score 0):

> However log.info(files) printed File[].

So, your given array is empty. Thats why you can't iterate over it! ;)

Comment: Sorry but the log.info("file"+files) printed file[]. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are using enhanced `for` loop, and Enhanced `for` loop guard itself from failing if list it is trying to iterate over is empty by not executing the block. That's exactly what is happening over here.

It's always a good practice to check for `empty` in situations where you might encounter it.